# Kotlin Multiplatform library exported to .framework crashes on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm trying to implement a library using Kotlin Multiplatform to use in my iOS project so I download the [official library template](https://github.com/Kotlin/multiplatform-library-template), which implements a Fibonacci sequence.

I did only 2 changes in this project:

1. I changed the Kotlin version from 1.9.0 to 1.9.21
2. In the file `library/build.gradle.kts` I updated the target `iosSimulatorArm64()` to output a `.framework` so I could use it on my Xcode iOS project, like this:

```
    iosSimulatorArm64() {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "TestLibrary"
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I ran the command `./gradlew iosSimulatorArm64Binaries` and the `TestLibrary.framework` was properly generated for me.

However, after I include this `.framework` in my project, my app crashes as soon as try to run the it (the Xcode project builds without any problem; it only crashes when I actually try to run the app), throwing this error:

[image: Xcode crash]

I not even tried to run the Fibonacci code in the iOS project yet; the app crashes by simply adding the framework and trying to run the app. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: That template is more for "libraries" and not so much for a shared-code repo, but of course, the framework should "work". Can you post more details? How are you including it the final app? That kind of thing. I would assume this is something config related, although currently no guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a reason why my app is crashing when I create a `.framework` and use it in Xcode, however I found a different solution that lets me achieve the same thing that I wanted to do originally: create a code in Kotlin Multiplatform and invoke this code in my iOS project using Swift.

So, instead of creating a `.framework` file I decided to create a `.xcframework`. Then when I added `xcframework` in my iOS project the app no longer crashed.

To make your KMP library output a `.xcframework` you just need to update your build.gradle.kts file and add this:

```
val frameworkName = "TestLibrary"
val xcf = XCFramework(frameworkName)
val iosTargets = listOf(iosSimulatorArm64()) // Include more targets here if you want

iosTargets.forEach {
    it.binaries.framework {
        baseName = frameworkName
        xcf.add(this)
    }
}
```